# Select and clear all elements except this

Tags: jquery

I have 5 inputs with attr `search`.

When user type something in any input, I search requested value in database.
But before searching, I want to clear all other search fields except one being edited.

Here is what I have:

```
$(document).on('input', 'input[search]', function(){

   var searchValue = $(this).val();

   //Now I want to clear all other input[search] fields, except $(this)

});
```

Should be simple, but can't figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("input[type=search]").on("input",function(){

        $("input[type=search]").not(this).val('');

    })

})
```

Final code :

```html
<html>
    <title>This is test</title>
    
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        Search 1 : <input type="search">
        <br><br>
        Search 2 : <input type="search">
        <br><br>
        Search 3 : <input type="search">
        <br><br>
        Search 4 : <input type="search">
        <br><br>
        Search 5 : <input type="search">
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("input[type=search]").on("input",function(){

                $("input[type=search]").not(this).val('');

            })

        })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/)** method to filter out any element from the selector.

```
$(document).on('input', 'input[search]', function(){    
   var searchValue = $(this).val();
   // avoid current element where `this` referst to current element
   $('input[search]').not(this).val('');  
});
```

---

```js
$(document).on('input', 'input[search]', function() {
  var searchValue = $(this).val();
  // avoid current element where `this` referst to current element
  $('input[search]').not(this).val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input search/>
<input search/>
<input search/>
<input search/>
<input search/>
<input search/>
<input search/>
```